# Wrong persistence.xml while testing

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am currently developing a Java SE application which uses Hibernate as an ORM-Tool. I wanted to use a different database for tests so I created a second persistence.xml file. The problem is, when I execute the tests, the wrong persistence.xml is loaded and used.

My file structure looks like this:

```
src
|- main
   |- resources
      |- META-INF
         |- persistence.xml  // This one is used
|- test
   |- resources
      |- META-INF
         |- persistence.xml  // This one should be used
```

The persistence.xml files look the same, only the mode is different.

Live:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:./data/mydb" />
```

Test:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:mydb" />
```

I wrote a test which checks if the right persistence unit is used, the code looks like this:

```
Session session = (Session)entityManager.getDelegate();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = session.getSessionFactory();
Map<String, Object> properties = sessionFactory.getProperties();
String url = (String) properties.get("hibernate.connection.url");

assertThat(url, containsString(":mem:"));  // Wrong url
```

Comment: How do you execute the tests?

Comment: I execute them via Netbeans (right-click -> Test File or Ctrl + F6)

Comment: I don't know anything about NetBeans. But make sure that NetBeans puts the test classes directory before the production classes directory in the classpath when executing the tests this way.

Comment: NetBeans just executes the maven test command. Where do I check if this is the case?

Comment: Ah. Then it must not just be a classpath ordering problem, because the surefire plugin does put test classes before production classes in the classpath (see http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html).